# Fortnightly task on Heroku scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the [Heroku Scheduler add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) set up and I came across techniques for running a task weekly. However, I need a task that runs every other week, but I can't think of any elegant/simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

How about setting it to run weekly on Heroku, but then in your actual task make the first step be to check if the task was already run last week, and if so abort. This would also involve storing the current date every time the task is successfully run.

Comment: Ah I was thinking of something not involving the database. Anyway, I am going to try getting the week number and then continuing the task if it is odd. Thanks anyway!